# MySQL dynamic transpose/pivot of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, unpivot

I've been trying to pivot a very sample table:

```
TYPE       | COUNT
___________________
'CHAINS'   | '38'
'INDEP'    | '64'
'SUPER'    | '25'
```

I've been reading tutorials, Stack Overflow answers and I've been looking for a good tutorial about transposing a table. I just can't understand it very well and I haven't been able to accomplish the following result:

```
CHAINS | INDEP | SUPER
_______________________
38     | 64    | 25
```

I know there are other questions similar to this one, but I just can't get the point from reading. Most examples use multiple tables to explain or just have code with no explanation, and I can't understand what's needed to do this. How can I accomplish this pivoted table?

---

### Edit 1

With the tutorials I've read, I've manage to get the following:

```
CHAINS | INDEP | SUPER
_______________________
38     | NULL  | NULL
NULL   | 64    | NULL
NULL   | NULL  | 25
```

I'd like the data to be in a single row without those null. I know there are tutorials and answers about this but I just don't understand clearly. I'd like an explanation of the logic to do this pivot table.

@bluefeet told me I needed an aggregate function. With sum() I got a single row

---

### Edit 2

This is the query I'm using works (thanks to @bluefeet) but it's not dynamic: I can't know for sure what columns I'll need.

```
SELECT
  sum(case when sq.TYPE = 'CHAINS' then sq.COUNT end) AS CHAINS,
  sum(case when sq.TYPE = 'INDEP' then sq.COUNT end) AS INDEPE,
  sum(case when sq.TYPE = 'SUPER' then sq.COUNT end) AS SUPER
from subquery1 sq
```

How can I get a similar result but with a dynamic query?

Comment: Are there only 3 types or there can be morethan 3?

Comment: There can be more than those 3 I've listed, that's why a dynamic SQL would be useful. I've just typed those few for the example. Thanks a lot for your kind help

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks, I'm reading exactly that answer, but I'm not very skilled with SQL, so I still don't get it, I don't understand it clearly u.u I've added to my question the result I'm getting

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Metafaniel Edit to include your query. It's possible you are grouping by too many columns.  If you group by too many columns that are distinct - you might be throwing off the result.

Comment: @bluefeet I've added my simple query. It's not even dynamic.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your interest! Well, I've got a subquery whose result is the first table in this question. I want to add these result to another query for a report and thus need to be in one row. Thanks again

Comment: @Metafaniel You aren't using an aggregate function -did you try `sum()` around your case like `sum(case when sq.TYPE = 'CHAINS' then sq.COUNT end) AS CHAINS`?

Comment: @bluefeet THANKS now it's in one row. BUT this is not dynamic, and I can't know for sure the info that will be the columns =/ So this works but if I hardcode the columns. Thanks again

Comment: @Metafaniel My answer here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns/12005676#12005676 should help

Comment: @Metafaniel If you solved this, then you should post an answer and accept it.